# Arkham Horror heralds with new cards

Tags: arkham-horror

Playing Arkham Horror with a herald. In the Herald variant rules, it doesn't say to shuffle the new cards in their respective decks.

Does this mean that the herald variant is played without the new cards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that the variant only describes the rules that are different than usual.

Note that it also doesn't say to shuffle the old cards in their respective decks.

This variant doesn't prevent you from using other components from the same expansion, components from other expansions, or rules from other variants.